# is there any way to connect flashdevelop to genymotion or bluestack

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, adb, flashdevelop

I use native overlay to load swf on starling but touch didnt work in emulator i want to connect flashdevelop to genymotion or bluestack. how can I do?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more 
research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).  Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: tnx peter.i research about this subject in several froum(starling) and find nothing and i have no idea to do that,before i ask guestion i read how to ask good question

Comment: When you create a mobile AS3 project in FD, you get a folder full of deploy BAT scripts. I run PackagerApp.bat to create APK, in the end it tries to connect to any available device to deploy the built APK there. I never tried it, but I think it's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure yours PATH environment includes path to /SDK/platforms-tools (or wherever your adb program is)
Then open commandline (terminal or cmd.exe), and run following command
adb install YourAppName.APK

This install flash APK to android virtual machine (as any other APK application package)

Comment: did you test it? are you achieve your answer?